# handling Mutiple Item values in XSLT with break statment

Tags: xslt

Source Structure:

```
 <XML_ITEM_TAB>
    <item>
    <Field1>Yyyy</Field1>
    <Field2>Yyyy</Field2>
    <O_VII>0</O_VII>
    <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
    <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
    </item>
    <item>
    <Field1>Yyyy</Field1>
    <Field2>Yyyy</Field2>
    <O_VII></O_VII>
    <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
    <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
    </item>
    <item>
    <Field1>Yyyy</Field1>
    <Field2>Yyyy</Field2>
    <O_VII>200.00</O_VII>
    <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
    <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
    </item>
    <item>
    <Field1>Yyyy</Field1>
    <Field2>Yyyy</Field2>
    <O_VII>100.00</O_VII>
    <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
    <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
    </item>
    </XML_ITEM_TAB>
```

Target Strucutre:

```
        <a:NFeGoods>
        <a:recordset>
        <a:nota_ini_one>
        <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
        <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
             <a:vII>
                 <xsl:value-of select="O_VII"/>
             </a:vII>
        </a:nota_ini_one>
        </a:recordset>
        </a:NFeGoods>
```

Requirement in XSLT:

1. `a:vII` field has 0:1 occurrence.
2. It has to get first `O_VII` value other than zero.
3. If no value other than zero exists in `O_VII` then it needs to be replaced with 0.00;
4. If no zero or valid value need to be replaced with `;`.

Examples of Required Output:

```
 1.IF valid non zero value exists:       
            <a:NFeGoods>
            <a:recordset>
            <a:nota_ini_one>
            <Field1>Yyyy</Field3>
            <Field2>Yyyy</Field4>
            <a:vII>200.00</a:vII>
            <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
            <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
            </a:nota_ini_one>
            </a:recordset>
            </a:NFeGoods>
 2.IF only zero value  exist for OVII field in one of the item:       
            <a:NFeGoods>
            <a:recordset>
            <a:nota_ini_one>
            <Field1>Yyyy</Field3>
            <Field2>Yyyy</Field4>
            <a:vII>0.00</a:vII>
            <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
            <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
            </a:nota_ini_one>
            </a:recordset>
            </a:NFeGoods>
3.If no zero or no non zero value exist for OVII field in all items:

            <a:NFeGoods>
            <a:recordset>
            <a:nota_ini_one>
            <Field1>Yyyy</Field3>
            <Field2>Yyyy</Field4>
            <a:vII>;</a:vII>
            <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
            <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
            </a:nota_ini_one>
            </a:recordset>
            </a:NFeGoods>

Also please note there are some other logic used for other nodes.So the logic need to appiled in inside node <a:vII>regured logic to get OVII value </a:vII>.
```

Comment: This is an example of very badly specified question: The source XML is still not well-formed even after the edit of @Mads Hansen. There is no wanted output provided. The question says "a:vII field has 0:1 occurrence." but in a very ambiguous comment the OP says: "a:VII has occurance 1:1 ". -1.

Comment: Please, provide (by editing the question) the exact wanted output for the specified source XML document.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, please see the edited structure . Regards, yeshwanth

Comment: Still complete mystery. Why `Field3` and `Field4` occure four times in the XML document but only two times in the wanted output? If this is a real requirement and not a mistake, which two of the four must be deleted?

Comment: Field 3 and Field 4 are dummy field do not think about it. Please look only node a:VII.I need to get value O:VII  inside the node.Also note <a:nota_ini_one>  has only one occurence and so we need only one value for field a:VII.

Answer (score 0):

**It is very difficult to understand what exactly is wanted -- just my guess**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:a="some:a">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <a:NFeGoods>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </a:NFeGoods>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <a:recordset>
   <a:nota_ini_one>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::O_VII)]"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vX" select=
      "/*/*/O_VII
            [number(.) = number(.)
           and
             not(. = 0)
            ]
              [1]
      "/>
     <xsl:variable name="vZerosOnly" select="not($vX)"/>
     <a:vII>
      <xsl:value-of select=
        "concat($vX, substring('0.00;', 1 div $vZerosOnly))"/>
     </a:vII>
   </a:nota_ini_one>
  </a:recordset>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Field1|Field2"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML (had to correct it as it is severely malformed!!!):**

```
<XML_ITEM_TAB>
    <item>
        <Field1>Yyyy</Field1>
        <Field2>Yyyy</Field2>
        <O_VII>0</O_VII>
        <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
        <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Field1>Yyyy</Field1>
        <Field2>Yyyy</Field2>
        <O_VII></O_VII>
        <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
        <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Field1>Yyyy</Field1>
        <Field2>Yyyy</Field2>
        <O_VII>200.00</O_VII>
        <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
        <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Field1>Yyyy</Field1>
        <Field2>Yyyy</Field2>
        <O_VII>100.00</O_VII>
        <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
        <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
    </item>
</XML_ITEM_TAB>
```

**the result is of the wanted format**:

```
<a:NFeGoods xmlns:a="some:a">
   <a:recordset>
      <a:nota_ini_one>
         <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
         <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
         <a:vII>200.00</a:vII>
      </a:nota_ini_one>
   </a:recordset>
   <a:recordset>
      <a:nota_ini_one>
         <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
         <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
         <a:vII>200.00</a:vII>
      </a:nota_ini_one>
   </a:recordset>
   <a:recordset>
      <a:nota_ini_one>
         <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
         <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
         <a:vII>200.00</a:vII>
      </a:nota_ini_one>
   </a:recordset>
   <a:recordset>
      <a:nota_ini_one>
         <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
         <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
         <a:vII>200.00</a:vII>
      </a:nota_ini_one>
   </a:recordset>
</a:NFeGoods>
```

Comment: a:VII has occurance 1:1 and shuould get first valid value(200.00) or if not valid value exist and zero exists need to be repalced with (0.00)

Comment: Required format: <a:NFeGoods xmlns:a="some:a">
       <a:recordset>
          <a:nota_ini_one>
             <Field3>Yyyy</Field3>
             <Field4>Yyyy</Field4>
             <a:vII>200.00</a:vII>
          </a:nota_ini_one>
       </a:recordset>
           </a:NFeGoods>
**a:VII has occurance 0:1 and shuould get  first valid value(200.00) or if not valid value exist  and zero exists need to be repalced with (0.00)

Comment: @user1140795: Please, edit your question and provide the exact wanted output for the provided source XML. Your source and explanations so far are extremely confusing.